# UIScrollView click coordinates

Tags: uiscrollview, touch, scale

I move a hidden uilabel to the tap point in a uiscrollview and then unhide it - works great. However when you pinch the uiscrollview to zoom in and tap again the label shows up in the wrong position. How can I scale the touchpoint by the scale of the uiscrollview to position it correctly?

-me

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    CGPoint longTapPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];   
    NSLog(@"LongTapPoint.x %f,LongTapPoint.y %f",longTapPoint.x,longTapPoint.y);
    uil_tapBldgLabel.center = CGPointMake(longTapPoint.x, longTapPoint.y);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to pass these touch events to the nextResponder so you do not get caught up with the scaling nuances.

Comment: Well - your comment got me thinking that why do I care about scaling? So I moved the label outside of the scroll and now it appears where I tap as intended.